# Using Jodd on Android with proguard

Tags: android, android-proguard, jodd

Jodd is a fantastic library, but I'm having trouble when using it with the release version of my app with Proguard. It occurs with the following line of code throwing an exception detailed belowL

```
            BeanCopy.beans(source, destination).copy();
```

Before the exception however, if I choose not to suppress warnings during the gradle build, several warnings referring to classes not included in the Android runtime come up, for example:

```
Warning:jodd.util.ClipboardUtil: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection
```

This is the exception thrown:

```
11-19 23:45:00.458 16897-16897/com.myfab5.mobile.debug D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-19 23:45:00.468 16897-16897/com.myfab5.mobile.debug E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-19 23:45:00.468 16897-16897/com.myfab5.mobile.debug E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.myfab5.mobile.debug, PID: 16897
11-19 23:45:00.468 16897-16897/com.myfab5.mobile.debug E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
11-19 23:45:00.468 16897-16897/com.myfab5.mobile.debug E/AndroidRuntime:     at b.e.c.a(Unknown Source)
11-19 23:45:00.468 16897-16897/com.myfab5.mobile.debug E/AndroidRuntime:     at b.a.g.a(Unknown Source)
11-19 23:45:00.468 16897-16897/com.myfab5.mobile.debug E/AndroidRuntime:     at b.a.g.a(Unknown Source)
11-19 23:45:00.468 16897-16897/com.myfab5.mobile.debug E/AndroidRuntime:     at b.a.g.b(Unknown Source)
11-19 23:45:00.468 16897-16897/com.myfab5.mobile.debug E/AndroidRuntime:     at b.a.a.a(Unknown Source)
11-19 23:45:00.468 16897-16897/com.myfab5.mobile.debug E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.myApp.android.services.copyBeans(Unknown Source)
11-19 23:45:00.468 16897-16897/com.myfab5.mobile.debug E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzk$zzb.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
11-19 23:45:00.468 16897-16897/com.myfab5.mobile.debug E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-19 23:45:00.468 16897-16897/com.myfab5.mobile.debug E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
11-19 23:45:00.468 16897-16897/com.myfab5.mobile.debug E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6837)
11-19 23:45:00.468 16897-16897/com.myfab5.mobile.debug E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-19 23:45:00.468 16897-16897/com.myfab5.mobile.debug E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-19 23:45:00.468 16897-16897/com.myfab5.mobile.debug E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
11-19 23:45:00.468 16897-16897/com.myfab5.mobile.debug E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
11-19 23:45:00.468 16897-16897/com.myfab5.mobile.debug E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid module: class b.e.j
11-19 23:45:00.468 16897-16897/com.myfab5.mobile.debug E/AndroidRuntime:     at b.a.a(Unknown Source)
11-19 23:45:00.468 16897-16897/com.myfab5.mobile.debug E/AndroidRuntime:     at b.e.j.a(Unknown Source)
11-19 23:45:00.468 16897-16897/com.myfab5.mobile.debug E/AndroidRuntime:
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Can Jodd be used with Proguard successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes :) You have several options:

- First, you might use `jodd-mobile.jar`. [This mobile version](http://jodd.org/download/#mobile-version) is a small bundle of core, bean and props modules, *without* all the system classes, like `ClipboardUtil` (which btw Im going to remove today :)
- Other solution is to fine-tune proguard to skip the Jodd classes, so you can put something like this in your proguard configuration:

```
-keep class javax.** { *; }
-keep class jodd.** { *; }
-keep class twitter4j.** { *; }
```

- If you feel adventurous, you can remove problematic classes from Jodd jars by your own script.

That's it. Enjoy Jodd!

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I was including jodd in my gradle script like this:     

compile 'org.jodd:jodd-bean:3.6.6'

I thought that would only include required classes, I'll try using the mobile jar now. Thanks again!

Comment: I tried the mobile jar, the only errors I get now are:

`code
Warning:jodd.util.PropertiesUtil$1: can't find referenced class jodd.io.findfile.* (multiple variations of this)
`
`code
Warning:jodd.datetime.JDateTime: can't find referenced class jodd.util.HashCode
`

`code
Warning:jodd.datetime.format.Iso8601JdtFormatter: can't find referenced class jodd.util.DateFormatSymbolsEx `

Comment: Ok, probably I havent update the mobile app for some time:) Anyway, those are just warnings, you should e able to continue with it for now, right?

Comment: I ignored the warnings, and it compiled fine, however trying to BeanCopy threw the same exception from above. :(

Comment: Oh man, I was being silly. I had a typo in the package name. It works great now, thanks so much for your help!